# Continuity of $f(x)g(x)$ for continuous functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How can I prove, using the epsilon-delta definition, that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous at some $x_0$, then $f(x)g(x)$ is also continuous at some $x_0$? I tried multiplying the inequalities $\mod(f(x)-f(x_0)) < \epsilon_1$ and $\mod(g(x)-g(x_0)) < \epsilon_2$, but I seem to be missing something.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Notice that $|f(x)g(x)-f(x_0)g(x_0)|=|f(x)g(x)-f(x_0)g(x)+f(x_0)g(x)-f(x_0)g(x_0)|$.

Comment: I tried using the triangle inequality on the first two terms and the last two terms, but I'm left with a mod(g(x)) in one of the terms, and I can't seem to proceed from there.

Comment: Try using continuity of $g$ to bound $g(x)$ on some small neighborhood of $x_0$ (apply the definition of continuity to $g$ at $x_0$ with $\varepsilon = 1$)

Comment: Why are you putting the word "mod" in everywhere? There is nothing in this that has anything to do with moduli.